# Disabling scrolling on event on maps

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js, bind

Found a potential solution, but it didnt seem to work.

```
$('svg')
  .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
  .on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom", null) // disables older versions of Firefox
  .on("wheel.zoom", null);
```

The issue is the map is being redrawn on click event. In some cases the zoom event is not being initialized, but the scrolling is still captured over the SVG element. When the scrolling is 'captured' it prevents the page from scrolling (which is not the desired behaviour). Is there a way to programmatically disable the capturing of the scroll event to zoom over the SVG?

D3 seems to be binding on the fly, and I have even tried explicitly interrupting the bindings to the extreme:

```
$('.map-container, #map, g, svg, d3, div').off('scroll').unbind('scroll').undelegate('scroll');
$(window).off('scroll').unbind('scroll').undelegate('scroll');
$(document).off('scroll').unbind('scroll').undelegate('scroll');
```

This may be a failing in my basic knowledge of bindings etc, or perhaps D3 was built in a very resilient way.

Any ideas? (If any answers please explain them, this is curious to me!)

Comment: You can't disable it explicitly without modifying the source code, but in your event handler you could check the source of the event and ignore if it comes from scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

It was a matter of getting precedence correct, and using the native function.

This works when calling via button click etc.

```
 $('.myClass').on('click',function() {
   d3.select('#map')
     .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
     .on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom", null)
     .on("wheel.zoom", null);
 });
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is:

```
$('svg').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: sadly no go... Thanks for showing me what was staring me in the face though, the combo

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RedEyedMonster There's not always a 100% accurate answer to all questions. In fact, in most cases this **would** work. Do you comment on all answers that turn out to be falsy in the end?

Comment: Your post was flagged as low quality because of its content and length.  When a post is flagged thus a number of set responses are available in the review process.  This seemed the most applicable.  Sorry if it caused offence.